# Media Gallery Items not displaying for Editor Role, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Something small and buggy but I can't seem to figure it out: Wordpress site was moved from testing server to live server and now after the move the media images that have been uploaded are no longer selectable or insertable in the 'Add Media' screen. This only happens to users with Editors or below (level 5 or less) while the Admin can see all the images. So it seemed that it should have been one of two things:

1. Rewriting folder permissions from 755 to 766 or 776 or even 777 did nothing to make the images appear in the 'Add Media' screen
2. Changing permissions using the 'User Role Editor' failed to change it as well.

The commonly cited 'deactivate all plugins' did not work either.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: [Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-36-master-list). I voted to close, as I think this Question is off-topic here and should be at [wordpress.se], but without debugging information it may be closed over there too. Also, define `we just moved a site live`.

Comment: Sorry if it's off-topic here, but I wouldn't have posted it unless I had already browsed Wordpress' documentation and forums already. I will re-edit my question to get a better scope for anyone looking at this though.

Comment: Swapping the theme to TwentyEleven/Twelve is also recommended for troubleshooting. If you create a new user, does it have the same issue? Does your *"move from testing to live"* procedure worked before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It did end up being an odd bug related to permissions restrictions due to a custom plugin we wrote for the site. It seemed we couldn't restrict access to dashboard items with both 'User Role Editor' *and* our custom plugin.

The only odd thing was that this did not seem to interfere while the site was on our testing server. Once it went live the permissions interfered with each other (?) but nonetheless it was discovered by systematic troubleshooting which plugin and then which functions were causing the error.

Comment: It would be great if you could be more specific as to which functions caused the errors.. I am running into a very similar problem now ..

Answer (score -1):

For you guys trying to find answer to similar question: If you run your Wordpress install on VPS or dedicated server which you had to configure yourself, remember to install PHP **GD Graphic Library**! It does not sometimes come natively and this library is needed to run all Wordpress media functionalities and even premium themes like Codeus uses this functionatility. You can install this library in terminal by typing

`apt-get install php5-gd`

Then type

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And you should be good to go!